# Thorax select menu collection first option

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, drop-down-menu, handlebars.js

I have two drop down select option menus being populated with json data via api call. I want to add the "Select" option as the first option which will have no value. Is there a way I can accomplish this in my view or in handlebars? I have tried the unshift method, but I can't seem to get the collection to successfully add the new option. Here is my code:

```
var productsMenuView = new Thorax.View({
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#products-template').html()),
    collection: new Thorax.Collection(
        [{
            id: selectMenu.id,
            name: selectMenu.name
        }]
    ),
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.fetch({url: 'products.json'});
        myString = this.collection;
        obj = myString.unshift({id: "0", name: "Select"});
        console.log(myString);
        return obj;
    }
});
```

Here is the Handlebars template:

```
<script id="products-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#collection tag="select" id="productSelect" class="modelSearchMenus"}}
    <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/collection}}
</script>
```

My menu displays this list of options:

```
<select id="productSelect" class="modelSearchMenus" data-view-cid="view21" data-view-helper="collection" data-collection-element="true" data-collection-cid="collection7">
<option value="Audio equipment" data-model-cid="c35">Audio equipment</option>
<option value="Cooktop" data-model-cid="c36">Cooktop</option>
<option value="Drill" data-model-cid="c37">Drill</option>
<option value="Fan" data-model-cid="c38">Fan</option>
<option value="Garbage disposal" data-model-cid="c39">Garbage disposal</option>
<option value="Microwave" data-model-cid="c40">Microwave</option>
<option value="Pruner" data-model-cid="c41">Pruner</option>
<option value="Range" data-model-cid="c42">Range</option>
<option value="Ratchet/nut driver" data-model-cid="c43">Ratchet/nut driver</option>
<option value="Vacuum" data-model-cid="c44">Vacuum</option>
<option value="Wall oven" data-model-cid="c45">Wall oven</option>
```

This is what I want the menu to display:

```
<select id="productSelect" class="modelSearchMenus" data-view-cid="view21" data-view-helper="collection" data-collection-element="true" data-collection-cid="collection7">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Audio equipment" data-model-cid="c35">Audio equipment</option>
<option value="Cooktop" data-model-cid="c36">Cooktop</option>
<option value="Drill" data-model-cid="c37">Drill</option>
<option value="Fan" data-model-cid="c38">Fan</option>
<option value="Garbage disposal" data-model-cid="c39">Garbage disposal</option>
<option value="Microwave" data-model-cid="c40">Microwave</option>
<option value="Pruner" data-model-cid="c41">Pruner</option>
<option value="Range" data-model-cid="c42">Range</option>
<option value="Ratchet/nut driver" data-model-cid="c43">Ratchet/nut driver</option>
<option value="Vacuum" data-model-cid="c44">Vacuum</option>
<option value="Wall oven" data-model-cid="c45">Wall oven</option>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just unshift another element into the collection if you can.

```
collection.fetch({
  success: function(collection) {
    collection.unshift(new Thorax.Model({name: 'Select'}));
  }
});
```

Ideally you could have an `id` to set the `" but if not you can add an if statement like:

```
{{#collection tag="select" id="productSelect" class="modelSearchMenus"}}
    <option value="{{#if name === 'Select'}}{{else}}{{name}}{{/if}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/collection}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it to your template would probably be the easiest way of accomplishing this:

```
<script id="products-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<option value="">Select</option>
{{#collection tag="select" id="productSelect" class="modelSearchMenus"}}
    <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/collection}}
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this already. The select menu disappears completely. Of course it was the most obvious choice, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: That is strange. Try console logging `myString`, you might need to unshift it into something inside the collection. When I look at a backbone collection, the actual items are inside `collection.models`

Comment: When I console log `myString`, `child {length: 25, models: Array[25], _byId: Object, cid: "collection4", _fetched: true…}
 
undefined` is returned. Do I need to use the `JSON.stringify()` method to return an array?

Comment: @OnlineOverlord the array of objects is inside `myString.models`, try console logging that and see what you should insert.

Comment: `[child, child, child, child, child, child, child, child, child, child, child]` this is returned. All of the attributes are showing up, but the `obj` isn't returning.

Comment: @onlineoverlord To be honest, you should try to debug why the template won't work. If you insert it as a model, it will probably be saved to the database every time. You obviously don't want that inside your database. Try to check the console for errors when the template renders. If there are none, try to inspect element on your <select> and see what it returns